# how to write new lines in CLI and web browser?

Tags: php

I am running a php script from CLI command and web browser. I need to dispaly new lines properly in both ways so that it does not print `"<br />"` in CLI and it shows new lines in browsers. Does anyone know how to write php function for this?

thanks for any helps

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could write a function to return the right thing based on the execution environment:

```
<?php 
if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli') 
{ 
   return PHP_EOL;
} 
else
{
   return "<BR/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Shorter: `function br() { return (PHP_SAPI === 'cli' ? "\n" : "<br />"); }`

Comment: I'd be tempted to use the `PHP_EOL` constant instead of `"\n"` to make sure you get the correct line ending for the platform.

Comment: Also, @Switz, when answering a question I try and keep it clear rather than short :)

Comment: you guys are great, this is exactly what i wanted!!

Comment: +1 for Switch. I like the short function he did. It is clear as there's no complex logic hidden behind and easy to read.

Comment: You can also define a variable storing the correct new line at the beginning of the script: `$br = PHP_SAPI === 'cli' ? "\n" : "<br/>";` and then use that `$br` whenever you need to write a new line.

Answer (score 8):

You can set the output's content type to `text/plain` to make browsers showing the content as, well, plain text like what you will see on CLI

```
header("Content-type: text/plain");
```

Put that before you output anything.

After that, always use `\n` for new lines

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the content in a variable and according to platform(page/cli) change 
 into \n

To do so you can write somethink like this:

```
<?php
    ob_start();

    $a = 1;
    $b = 2;
    $c = $a + $b;
    echo "Sum of $a and $b is <br /> $c";

    $content = ob_get_clean();
    $type= php_sapi_name();

    if ($type == 'cli' || $type == 'cgi-fcgi') {
        str_replace("<br />", "\n", $content);
    }

    echo $content;

?>
```

Comment: Or the other way around: use `\n` and call `nl2br()` if needed

Comment: @Sirko has answered exactly that earlier :)

Answer (score 1):

simply

```
$newline = PHP_SAPI === 'cli' ? "\n" : "<br>";
```

and then replace all \n on code with {$newline}

eg:

```
  echo "Try to Load Json From 1C for all Data{$newline}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your code using `\n`. For the web based version apply [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) afterwards.