# How do i write new line \r\n in php?

Tags: php, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP - how to create a newline character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238433/php-how-to-create-a-newline-character)

I'm trying to create a csv file.
But all i get is one row.
I thought

```
echo '\r\n' . $lineStr;
```

would create a new line.

I have added the following headers:

```
header("Content-Type:   application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myFile.xls");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - how to create a newline character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238433/php-how-to-create-a-newline-character) See also [Print newline in PHP in single quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531969/print-newline-in-php-in-single-quotes)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need [double quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double):

```
"\r\n"
```

Comment: Yes. That's obvious. Spend nnn minutes on this.
Thanks for the quick answer.