# \n or \n in php echo not print

Tags: php, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Print newline in PHP in single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531969/print-newline-in-php-in-single-quotes)
>   [Difference between single quote and double quote string in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-string-in-php)

```
$unit1 = 'paragrahp1';
$unit2 = 'paragrahp2';
echo '<p>' . $unit1 . '</p>\n';
echo '<p>' . $unit2 . '</p>';
```

This is displaying (on view source):

```
<p>paragraph1</p>\n<p>paragraph2</p>
```

but isnt what I’m expecting, not printing the new line, what can be?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In the OP's defense, if they're asking such an elementary question, I wouldn't make the assumption they know about PHP's interpolation.

Comment: and [Difference between single quote and double quote string in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-string-in-php)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

PHP only interprets escaped characters (with the exception of the escaped backslash `\\` and the escaped single quote `\'`) when in double quotes (`"`)

This works (results in a newline):

```
"\n"
```

This does not result in a newline:

```
'\n'
```

Comment: `'\n'` "works" just fine. It prints the string `\n`, as documented.

Comment: Teehee that's better ;-)

Comment: Escaped single quote(\') works in single quotes('') ,and Escaped double quote(\") works in double quotes("").

Answer (score 13):

Better use PHP_EOL ("End Of Line") instead. It's cross-platform.

E.g.:

```
$unit1 = 'paragrahp1';
$unit2 = 'paragrahp2';
echo '<p>' . $unit1 . '</p>' . PHP_EOL;
echo '<p>' . $unit2 . '</p>';
```

Answer (score 7):

Escape sequences (and variables too) work inside [double quoted](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) and [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) strings. So change your code to:

```
echo '<p>' . $unit1 . "</p>\n";
```

PS: One clarification, single quotes strings do accept two escape sequences:

- `\'` when you want to use single quote inside single quoted strings
- `\\` when you want to use backslash literally

Comment: Thanks to you and other answers,
answers withing 1 minute, wow.

Answer (score 3):

`\n` must be in double quotes!

```
echo "hello\nworld";
```

Output

```
hello
world
```

---

A nice way around this is to use PHP as a more of a templating language

```
<p>
    Hello <span><?php echo $world ?></span>
</p>
```

Output

```
<p>
    Hello <span>Planet Earth</span>
</p>
```

Notice, all newlines are kept in tact!

Answer (score 2):

`\n` must be in double quotes!

```
 echo '<p>' . $unit1 . "</p>\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$unit1 = "paragrahp1";             
$unit2 = "paragrahp2";  
echo '<p>'.$unit1.'</p>';  
echo '<p>'.$unit2.'</p>';
```

Use Tag `<p>` always when starting with a new line so you don't need to use /n type syntax.