# Line break in PHP

Tags: php, html, foreach, newline

I am trying to create a newline character in my foreach loop. After the URL I am trying to create a newline and then have a "------" between the title and content. After this there is supposed to be a space between the next URL. I have the space but I can't seem to get the line break. When I echo "\t" or "\n" in the loop nothing happens. When I use HTML in the loop it won't work, gives too many spaces.

```
for($i=0; $i < 4 ;$i++)
{
foreach ($json as $URL)
    {
        echo $URL ['results'][$i]['url'];
        echo "---------------";
        foreach ($json as $TITLE)
        {
              echo $TITLE ['results'][$i]['title'];
              echo "--------";
        }
        foreach ($json as $content)
              echo $content['results'][$i]['content'];
        echo "---------------- ";
    }
}
```

Is there a function in php besides "\n" or another way of manipulating the HTML to insert the line break?

TIA

Comment: you can use echo '<br>'

Comment: Try a light-fix `echo $TITLE ['results'][$i]['title'] . "&nbsp;";`
Non-breakable space wont give much space taht you want to avoid.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531969/print-newline-in-php-in-single-quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531969/print-newline-in-php-in-single-quotes)

Comment: why dont you just use <br> or nl2br()

Comment: When I use    echo"<br \>"; in the first foreach loop it gives me the url, 3 spaces and then the title and content. I'm thinking it must have something to do with the foreach loop itself

Comment: Cheers Ignat, I just used echo Surl['results'][['$i']['url']."<br />" which works perfectly, and gives me an idea on another problem as to  how to hyperlink the urls. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things you can do:

1: Use `<br>` as line break. If you use that, you should also consider using `<hr>` to insert the horizontal line.

```
some text<br>
<hr>
some other text<br>
```

2: Use `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags around your text to output preformatted text. You can then use `\n` and `\t` to format your text.

```
<pre>
some text\n
-------\n
some other text\n
</pre>
```

Answer (score 3):

This might the one you are searching for

```
for($i=0; $i < 4 ;$i++)
{
foreach ($json as $URL)
    {
        echo $URL ['results'][$i]['url'];
    echo "<br/>";        
    echo "---------------";
        foreach ($json as $TITLE)
        {
              echo $TITLE ['results'][$i]['title'];
              echo "--------";
        }
        foreach ($json as $content)
              echo $content['results'][$i]['content'];
        echo "---------------- ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

\n doesn't work in HTML. If you view source of the document you will however see the line breaks. Use html markup like

```
Test line break<br />
<p>paragraph</p>
<p>paragraph</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `<br />` to echo statements. as in html we use this for line breaks.

```
echo "Content"."<br />";
```

This would give line breaks in HTML format.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 echo "<br />";
```

instead of

```
 echo "---------------- ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use echo '
';

```
<?php
    echo "first line.<br />Second line.';
?>
```

or nl2br() function,

```
<?php
    echo nl2br("first line.\nSecond line.");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider
`echo "<hr /> ";`