# fpdf ignoring \n line break in multiCell or WriteHTML

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, fpdf

I have a 6 column quote form which I build using fpdf using the MultiCell feature. My issue is that in the 3rd column I have the description which has multiple lines of text that need a line break. You can see that replacing the html entity with \n only prints the character \n. I have tried it in quotes both single and double and tried CHR(10), it doesn't matter it treats the description as a string and outputs the string.

[image]

[image]
The data for the column "description" is in html string:

```
$description = "205 - Base Cap 0.717 X 3.11<br>Cypress #2<br>Mill finish<br>Exact<br>Sand<br>Kerf<br>End dado 2.625" below dado.<br>Prepare for flush bolt HW-24EFB10B<br>10/10&emsp;80/3";
```

To create the row I use the following code:

```
$description = str_replace('<br>','\n',$description);
$pdf->Row(array($itemNumber,$stk_code,$description,$quantity,$unit_price,$lineNet));
```

Which calls the Row function to create a MultiCell row:

```
var $widths;
var $aligns;

function SetWidths($w)
{
    //Set the array of column widths
    $this->widths=$w;
}

function SetAligns($a)
{
    //Set the array of column alignments
    $this->aligns=$a;
}

function Row($data)
{
    //Calculate the height of the row
    $nb=0;
    for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
        $nb=max($nb,$this->NbLines($this->widths[$i],$data[$i]));
    $h=15*$nb;
    //Issue a page break first if needed
    $this->CheckPageBreak($h);
    //Draw the cells of the row
    for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
    {
        $w=$this->widths[$i];
        $a=isset($this->aligns[$i]) ? $this->aligns[$i] : 'L';
        //Save the current position
        $x=$this->GetX();
        $y=$this->GetY();
        //Draw the border
        $this->Rect($x,$y,$w,$h);
        //Print the text
        $this->MultiCell($w,15,$data[$i],0,$a);
        //Put the position to the right of the cell
        $this->SetXY($x+$w,$y);
    }
    //Go to the next line
    $this->Ln($h);
}
```

I have also tried WriteHTML but it returns the text less any html entities visible on screen.

Comment: Put double quotes (") around your \n so it is `"\n"` instead of `'\n'` See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531969/print-newline-in-php-in-single-quotes)

Comment: When I first looked at your answer I thought this is dumb as I tried double quotes, escaping the quotes and what I thought was every variation BUT I missed this simple one. I changed the line to read $description = str_replace('<br>',"\n",$description); And it works a big thank you to you.

Answer (score 2):

You should use double quotes `"` around your `\n` instead of single quotes `'`.

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> The simplest way to specify a string is to enclose it in single quotes
>   (the character ').
>
> To specify a literal single quote, escape it with a backslash (). To
>   specify a literal backslash, double it (\). All other instances of
>   backslash will be treated as a literal backslash: this means that the
>   other escape sequences you might be used to, such as \r or \n, will be
>   output literally as specified rather than having any special meaning.
>
> If the string is enclosed in double-quotes ("), PHP will interpret [escape sequences such as \n]